# Why does $(3\sqrt3)^2 = 27$?

Tags: arithmetic, irrational-numbers

How does $(3\sqrt3)^2 = 27$?

I've tried to solve this using binomial expansion and using the FOIL method from which I obtain $9 + 3\sqrt3 +3\sqrt3 + 3$.
it has been a while since I've done this kind of thing so it may be something obvious that I can't see.

Comment: FOIL?  There is no binomial here.  $9 + 3 \sqrt{3} + 3 \sqrt{3} + 3$ would be $(3 + \sqrt{3})^2$, not $(3 \sqrt{3})^2$.

Comment: ah yes. basically expanding in the form (a•b)(a•b) edit: in fact that's (a+-b)(a+-b) too. my bad

Comment: The total reputation of the people in this page is excessively too damn high!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Recall that $$(ab)^2 = (a)^2 (b)^2$$

Here, $a = 3$ and $b = \sqrt 3$.

$$(3 \sqrt 3)^2 = (3)^2(\sqrt 3)^2 = 9 \cdot 3 = 27.$$

Comment: I wonder if there is a 2.5x nice answer? :-) +1

Answer (score 12):

If you *really* insist on expanding, just use the fact that $3\sqrt{3} = \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{3}$, and therefore expand away $(\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{3})^2$ using the trinomial expansion formula $(a+b+c)^2 = a^2 + b^2 +c^2 +2ab+2bc+2ac$.

**Later edit:**

And if you *really* insist on using FOIL, then use a little imagination to write $3\sqrt{3} = 2\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{3}$, thus your desired expression becoming $(2\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{3})(2\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{3})$.

Answer (score 8):

Your mistake is that $9+3\sqrt3+3\sqrt3+3=(3+\sqrt3)^2$. However $3\sqrt3\neq3+\sqrt3$.

As other answers indicate, $(3\sqrt3)^2=(\sqrt{3\cdot3^2})^2=(\sqrt{27})^2=27$.

Answer (score 7):

Other people have basically already said it, but the FOIL is only something that you can apply when you have expressions of exactly this form:
$$
(a + b)(c+d).
$$
In this case you do: (F)irst (O)utside (I)nside (L)ast: The First part of $(a + b)^2$ is $ac$. The Outside is $ad$, the Inside if $bc$ and the Last is $bd$. In all you get
$$
ac + ad + bc + bd.
$$

Now consider what happens when you have
$$
(a+b)^2 = (a+b)(a+b).
$$
In this case you get
$$
aa+ ab + ba + bb = a^2 + ab + ab + b^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2.
$$

Now, you are asking about what to do with
$$
(3\sqrt{3})^2
$$
Note that this is not of exactly the form $(a+b)(c+d)$ or $(a+b)^2$. You have the *product* of $3$ and $\sqrt{3}$ and to use FOIL you would need the sum $3+\sqrt{3}$. Therefore it doesn't make sense to use FOIL here. It simply isn't applicable (unless you rewrite the expression first as explain in one of the other answers).

---

So what do you do in this case? Your expression is exactly of the form
$$
(ab)^2
$$
with $a=3$ and $b = \sqrt{3}$. And then we have a rule that says that
$$
(ab)^2 = a^2b^2.
$$
So you get
$$
(3\sqrt{3})^2 = 3^2(\sqrt{3})^2 = 9\cdot 3 = 27.
$$
And that is it.

---

You could also do it slightly differently by using the rule/definition
$$
(ab)^2 = abab 
$$
So
$$
(3\sqrt{3})^2 = 3\sqrt{3}\cdot3\sqrt{3} = 3\cdot 3\cdot \sqrt{3}\sqrt{3} = 9 \sqrt{3\cdot 3} = 9\sqrt{9} = 9\cdot 3 = 27.
$$
Here we also used that the rule $\sqrt{c}\sqrt{d} = \sqrt{cd}$.

Comment: FOIL "simply isn't applicable"? How about writing $3\sqrt{3} = 2\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{3}$?

Comment: @baudolino: Yes, I just saw your edit and upvoted your answer. One can of course rewrite the expression so that FOIL works, but as it is written $3\sqrt{3}$ you can't. You have to rewrite first.

Comment: True. Although, in this particular instance, I wish mike would tell us if he struggles with the difference between $(a+b)^2$ and $(ab)^2$, or whether there is something more fundamental at work, such as not realizing that $(\sqrt{3})(\sqrt{3}) = 3$.

Comment: @baudolino: I agree.

Comment: The last part here is the best answer.

Comment: Except don't use the 'rule' $\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}=\sqrt{ab}$. Dy definition $\sqrt{3}\cdot\sqrt{3}=3$.

Answer (score 4):

$(3\sqrt{3})^2=3^2\cdot\sqrt{3}^2=9\cdot 3=27$

Comment: sorry, I should've added this into my question. I _do_ understand how _this_ method works, but I just don't understand why FOIL or binomial expansion return something different

Comment: @mike: FOIL only applies when you are multiplying two ***expressions***, each with two ***terms***.  You are multiplying two expressions each with one term, with two ***factors***. (The highlighted words have very specific distinct meanings in mathematics.)

Comment: lock colleague explained below, so I believe that there is no need to repeat the same to me

Answer (score 3):

To use FOIL or binomial expansion, the term has to be like this:
$$
(3 + \sqrt{3})^2
$$

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an answer, but it's relevant and doesn't fit into a comment. You seem to have a misunderstanding of what FOIL is.

FOIL only works when you're multiplying $(a + b)(c + d)$. But why does it only work then? Likely, you were just taught it as a rule, with no explanation or justification for it, because high school doesn't do that sort of thing enough.

Think of it this way: FOIL isn't a new rule, it's just a way to think about the distributive law twice:

$$(a + b)(c + d) = (a + b)c + (a + b)d = (ac + bc) + (ad + bd) = ac + ad + bc + bd$$

Note how $ac$ is the firsts, $ad$ is the outers, $bc$ is the inners, and $bd$ is the lasts. Does it make more sense why you can't FOIL $(ab)\cdot(cd)$ now?

Answer (score 0):

$x=(3\sqrt{3})^2$

$\sqrt{x}=3\sqrt{3}$

$\frac{\sqrt{x}}{3}=\sqrt{3}$

$\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{3}\right)^2=3$

$\frac{x}{3^2}=3$ (Assuming $x>0$).

$x=3*9$

$x=27$

Answer (score -2):

Here is a rule I think ...

1. $(a\sqrt b)^2 = (\sqrt (a^2.b)^2$
2. $(3\sqrt 3)^2 = (\sqrt (3^2.3)^2$
3. $(3\sqrt 3)^2 = (\sqrt (9.3)^2$
4. $(3\sqrt 3)^2 = (\sqrt (27)^2$
5. $(3\sqrt 3)^2 $=  27

Henced proved....